# Is it okay to say "I can play the piano by music notes"?

Tags: phrase-requests

Is it okay to say "I can play the piano by music notes" (meaning that if you gave me a sheet of paper with some music notes on it, I would have no problem reproducing that piece of music by looking at that sheet of paper and simultaneously playing the piano) or there is a better way of expressing this thought?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of saying "I can play the piano by music notes", it would be more understandable to say:

> I can play piano by reading sheet music

This means that, given a piece of sheet music, you can play the piece. If you can not only read sheet music, but you can play a piece you have never seen before on the first try, you can say:

> I can play the piano by sight-reading.

Or,

> I can sightread on the piano

As [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sight_reading) explains, sight-reading is:

> the reading and performing of a piece of written music, specifically when the performer has not seen it before

Comment: D'oh. Good answer...beating me by 5 seconds.

Comment: I've heard the formulation "I can sight-read" used a lot when the instrument in given by context : This piano player is an excellent sight-reader! How would you say "I'm an excellent sight-reader *on the* / *with* / *at* piano"

Comment: @Shawn I don't understand the second half of your comment. You ask "how would you say..." to something I never said

Comment: @simchona I am trying to figure out which is good between *on the*, *with*, and *at* in the sentence I gave which uses the verb sight-reading which your answer brings up. The sentences you provide, although correct, don't ring a bell to me as much as I would have expected and I believe there may be a more standard way of saying this... Not sure.

Comment: @Shawn you might say. "I can sightread on the piano"

Answer (score 5):

The term I am most familiar with is [**sightread**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sightread).

> to read (as a foreign language) or **perform (music) without previous preparation or study**

Then you could say that you can "sightread for/on the piano".

Also some people may prefer to use a hyphen in the term, **sight-read**.

Comment: +1 for using sight-read. (5 seconds off or not, I like your answer)

Comment: Would that be *for* or *on* then? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

A typical way of saying this is "I read sheet music."

Comment: Though that can mean you read without knowing how to play.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to retain the structure of the popular expression "to play by ear," I would use "to play by **score**".

Comment: I honestly don't think (as someone who studied music) that anyone would use this.

Comment: I found a few references online, but it's not that common.  Still, I was emphasizing the parallel structure which might be nice in dialog.  But point taken,  I won't defend this too much.  :-)